# How to execute an `explain select` on a laravel builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, explain

I know I could get the raw query from the query log, paste in all the bound variables (also found in the query log), slap a `explain` at the front of the query, and run it directly in the mysql console to get the explanation for the query.... but is there any quicker way to get the explanation?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
$query = User::where("favorite_color", "blue");

dd($query->explain());
```

(obviously, the actual query is going to be much more complicated and have some joins)

I tried adding on the `explain` like this:

```
$query->selectRaw("explain select user.*");
```

But this resulted in a query that started with:

```
select explain select...
```

... which is just invalid sql.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no function to do this. You will have to create the query using the query builder and prepend `EXPLAIN` manually. Then you can manually execute this query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of [Laravel 8.12](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.12.0), you can simply call `->explain()` on the query builder, like you described in your question. Or use `->explain()->dd()` to die & dump the explanation.

Example:

```
User::where("favorite_color", "blue")->explain()->dd();
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change the code to raw sql,

Secondly then add explain before the raw sql,

And use `DB::select()`

```php
$query = User::where("favorite_color", "blue");
$bindings = collect($query->getBindings())->map(function($q) {
    return is_string($q)? "\"$q\"": $q;
})->all();
$sql_with_bindings = str_replace_array('?', $bindings, $query->toSql());
DB::select("explain ".$sql_with_bindings);
```

Comment: This is not as elegant as I was hoping, but it seems that there's no way to do this without converting the builder into raw SQL.

Comment: It's worth noting that the values in `$query->getBindings()` need to be wrapped in quotes, or any bound variables with white space in them will generate bad SQL.

Comment: @Skeets I have updated the answer for the string value.