# Retrieve collection with calculation takes too long to load (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance

I'm working on a collection that needs to calculate some data for each row and it takes too much time to load into view. The problem is I defined an accessor and inside that accessor will perform some calculation and if the data is too big or when user retrieve too many row at once.

Example Model:

```
public function getCalculationAttribute()
{

    $score_ids = Score::whereIn('id', $this->scores->pluck('score_id'))->pluck('id');
    $count_score = $count_score->count();
    $penalties = Penalty::whereIn('score_id', $score_ids->toArray())->count();
    $balance = $count_score - $penalties;
    $another_score =  $count_score > 0 ? ($balance / $count_score) * 0.7 : 0;

    return [
        'field_a' => $count_score,
        'field_b' => $penalties,
        'field_c' => $balance,
        'field_d' => $another_score
    ];
}
```

Example Controller

```
public function index(){
    $data = ExampleModel::get();
    return view('example', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Example blade

```
@foreach($data as $row)
    <p>{{ $row->calculation['field_a']}}</p>
    <p>{{ $row->calculation['field_b']}}</p>
    <p>{{ $row->calculation['field_c']}}</p>
    <p>{{ $row->calculation['field_d']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

When I didn't need the calculation attribute it works perfectly fine, but when I do and I know each of them will be running query and calculation and it will take forever. Is there any good practice on retrieving data with calculation or any suggestion I can modify this to improve the performance? The code above is just an example. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to check these issues? Are the fields indexed at database level?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981047/how-to-execute-an-explain-select-on-a-laravel-builder could help to inspect the execution plan

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes I've checked all field that should've indexed are indexed but I think  maybe data was too big and each individual record need to run the query and calculation that's why it takes too long. I was wondering should I create a log table and run a CRON to save daily calculation or any other better way

Comment: This seems like a lot of really redundant querying : $score_ids = Score::whereIn('id', $this->scores->pluck('score_id'))->pluck('id');  you seem to have the score_ids from the inner pluck('score_id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an N+1 query issue with this code. Each time you loop `$data` and call `$row->calculation`, you're executing 3 extra queries:

```php
Score::whereIn(...);
$this->scores->pluck('score_id');
...
Penalty::whereIn(...);
```

You're calling `$row->calculation` 4 times... I'm pretty sure that means 12 additional queries per row in `$data`, since `get{Whatever}Attribute()` doesn't have any kind of caching/logic to know you've called it already.

If you save `$row->calculations` to a variable, you can reduce that a bit:

```php
@foreach($data as $row)
  @php $calculations = $row->calculations; @endphp
  <p>{{ $calculations['field_a']}}</p>
  <p>{{ $calculations['field_b']}}</p>
  <p>{{ $calculations['field_c']}}</p>
  <p>{{ $calculations['field_d']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Additionally, you can eager load the `scores` relationship to reduce it a bit more:

```php
$data = ExampleModel::with('scores')->get();
```

Including that will make `$this->scores->pluck('score_id');` use the pre-loaded data, and not call an additional query.

Lastly, try to use relationships for your `Score::whereIn()` and `Penalty::whereIn()` queries. I'm not sure how you would define them, but if you did, then including those in your `->with()` clause will hopefully completely remove this N+1 query issue.

Comment: Thank you so much this improve my performance a lot by saving it into a variable! from a 8 to 10 seconds loading to only 2 to 3 seconds.

Comment: Haha yeah, with that change, you're moving from 12 additional queries per row to 2, which is a huge improvement. And again, this can be optimized further if you can get the result of those 2 nested queries into a relationship. Happy to help! 